# Changing the tab widget design in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5, qtabwidget

I have been searching for a way to alter the standard tab widget in Qt off and on for about 2 weeks. Does anyone know how to do this? My goal is for it too like similar to the picture posted[image]

Comment: did the suggested answers work for you? If yes, you should accept the corresponding answer. If not, write what worked in an answer of your own.

Answer (score 2):

In a very simplified version, you could use this stylesheet:
Make use of a transparent .png image to make sure you get the arrow effect.

```
QTabBar::tab {
    border-image: url(:/[file].png); /*Image file of idle state*/
    min-width:75px; /*image width*/
    min-height:25px; /*image height*/
    margin-left:-15px; /*Overlap tabs*/
}

QTabBar::tab:selected{
    border-image: url(:/[file2].png); /*Image file of selected state*/     
}
```

Comment: Do I need to put the file location of the .png file I'm attempting to use.

Comment: I attempted putting the location of the file in the brackets and it merely deleted the original task bar and didn't bring the .png file in.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve what you are looking for with just the Qt style sheet without needing to overwrite the paint method.

You can use `border-image` property of the `QTabBar::tab` in the Qt Style Sheet. Just read the documentation as to how you could style `border-image`. There is a nice explanation in the [documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/stylesheet-examples.html#id-894896ee-44bc-4282-871a-31ca3a19f683).